# Why does `if` change the scope of this variable

Tags: go

If I have something like this

Case 1:

```
if str, err := m.something(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

fmt.Println(str)  //str is undefined variable
```

Case 2:

```
str, err := m.something(); 

fmt.Println(str)  //str is ok
```

My question is why does the scope of the variable `str` change when its used in a format like this

```
 if str, err := m.something(); err != nil {
        return err
        //str scope ends
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `if` statements (and `for`, and `switch`) are [implicit blocks](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blocks), according to the language spec, and `:=` is for both declaration and assignment. If you want `str` to be available after the `if`, you could declare the variables first, and then assign to them in the if statement:

```golang
var s string
var err error

if str, err = m.something(); err != nil
// ...
```